# CSS Style not recognized in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

This is driving me nuts. Here is some HTML and CSS that I have on a sample page. The first intent was to have LI without any markers. I have tried everything I could, but the list items will show up with standard decimal marker. I used developer tool that comes with IE9 to inspect UL and LI elements. It seems that IE does not recognize "recentAnnouncementsList" css class at all. These elements do not show the style applied on it. This whole set up works perfectly on Chrome. What am I missing?

Thanks

```
ul.recentAnnouncementsList
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.recentAnnouncementsList li
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.recentAnnouncementsList li a{
    color:#675DF0;text-decoration:none; font-size:0.85em;
}

ul.recentAnnouncementsList li span{
    display: block;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
}

<td>
<div>
<ul class="recentAnnouncementsList" id="recentAnnouncements">
<li><a href="#">Released 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Release 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: IE9 isn't loading a cached version of the stylesheet, is it?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/kkqxK/1/

Comment: No, no cached style sheet is loaded. I have made that sure by adding some dummy value somewhere else to make sure that i can verify it.

Comment: @Madmartigan: The same style has worked fine on another site on IE9. But when I tried on different site, it just does not work for IE9. I have looked to make sure that there is no other style sheet with same style names that may override or anything like that. It seems that there is some combination of styles that may be causing problem. I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem.
The problem was that I had added a new CSS class named "container" in the file. I am not sure if this is some bug in IE and FF, but CSS file was getting clipped at start of that style. I found this out by looking in the developer tools for IE. When i looked at loaded file in IE, it was not complete. All my styles related to my UL/LI tags were present after that class definition. After I deleted "container" class from file, everything went back to normal.

Thanks for all your input and suggestions.

Comment: Hey @ByteBlocks thanks so much for this.  When you say that you looked at your CSS in developer tools, where exactly did you look for it?  I'm looking in Network tab under the Response Body for the CSS and I'm seeing my CSS in there but wondering if there's another place to check the way in which it's actually parsing the CSS not just the raw download.

Comment: Easiest will be, right on the element in browser (IE, Chrome) and from context menu choose "Inspect Element". Then you will be able to see the styles that are being applied to your element. Any style that is being overwritten will show up with a line through it. Let me know if this description helps.

Comment: I fought with IE for about two weeks straight and this is what the issue was. Good lord, I'm so glad I found this! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

for my project I once rendered IE9 as IE8 by rendering it with meta tag of html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

so the same css worked for both

Comment: I was facing this issue, Tanx dude

Answer (score 0):

IE 6-9 all have limit on the number of selectors declared in a CSS file. I assume that styles declared for .recentAnnouncementsList are located above the limit and completely ignored. There are tools are resources which help to split big CSS files into several parts and keep the number of selectors in a single file below the limit:

- [blesscss](http://blesscss.com/) - command line tool
- [css_splitter](https://github.com/zweilove/css_splitter) - for Rails apps
- [gulp-bless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bless) - for NodeJS projects